# How can i link hadoop with snort?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, packet-capture, snort

I'm trying to process snort packets by hadoop, I captured packet using snort by typing:

```
 snort -v
```

and then logging them in snort log file by:

```
snort -l /var/log/snort -b
```

I want to process them by hadoop platform to analyze them to match specific rule and then do some action.

How can I link hadoop with snort, and make hadoop read snort log file?

Comment: You would probably upload you log file to HDFS and then use MapReduce/Pig/Hive etc to process the data.

Comment: How can I upload the log file to HDFS ??, Is there a specific way to make hadoop read snort log file automatically instead of manually upload the log file every time ?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at https://flume.apache.org/.

Comment: Ok,I will ,Thank you.

Comment: Apache Metron might give you some ideas as well: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/METRON/Snort+Capture+Design

Comment: Can I use them with hadoop and snort ?